# send parameter with jstl

Tags: jsp, jstl

I need send the `idBeneficiario` on the `href=""`, but I can't catch the value of the `name="Expediente"`, because don't get the value of this. Anybody can help me please.

```html
Nro. Expediente: <input type="text" name="Expediente" value="">
<br>
<br> 
<a class="btn btn-warning" href="Bene?accion=FND&idBeneficiario" role="button">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
</a>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Where is your JavaScript? Do you have JS at all? If you want to do it without JS you need to put all this inside a `<form>`.

Comment: thank you for your help I already achieve it, I am new to The programing